# Uploading iOS application to apple store connect for testing

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a problem that I got task to upload new build of application to Apple Store Connect for testing, the problem is that only person who did it before is on holiday. I checked some tutorials and documentations but I don't have upload button. Can anyone help me?

So far after I finished new version of app, In XCode: I changed team to this one for distribution and increased build number by one,

Then I went to Product> Achives

then After it is done, I have new window where on the right side I can see blue button "Distribute App" and "Validate"

Then I click on Distribute App>Development>AppThining = IPhoneX,Rebuild from Bitcode>Automatically manage signing>

And here according to all guides I found should be upload button, Howeber all what i have is "Cancel" "Previous" and "Export"

Comment: use option iOS App Store then upload the option you chosen is for local development . Choose the first option and in Distribute App

Comment: @Zireka above Validate App button there is "Distribute App" Please use that to update IPA directly

Comment: @Vinodh you were right! half of day searching yesterday had no result and 5 min of stackoverflow was enough:) Thanks dude you saved me